# Unable to add multiple graphicsitem in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, paint, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to paint multiple points in `graphicsscene` on mouse clicks. The point class is inherited from `QGraphicsItem` class. The following pieces of code show painting and mouse events respectively.

```
void point:: paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget){
if(mPaintFlag){
    QPen paintpen(Qt::red);
    paintpen.setWidth(4);

    QPointF p1;
    p1.setX(x1);
    p1.setY(y1);

    painter->setPen(paintpen);
    painter->drawPoint(p1);
    update();
   }
}

void point::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e)
{
if(e->button()==Qt::LeftButton) {
    if(mClick){
        x1 = e->pos().x();
        y1 = e->pos().y();

        mClick = false;
        mPaintFlag = true;
        update();
    }
    _store.set_point(e->pos());
    store_point.push_back(_store);
    qDebug() << _store.getValue();
    qDebug() << "Size of vector =" << store_point.size();
    update();
}
```

}

The coordinates of each point plotted are stored in a vector. But I am able to see only the first point painted in the `graphicsscene`. The other points' coordinates are stored in the vector but those points plotted subsequently are not visible in the scene.

How to achieve all points being painted in the scene?

Comment: What does your function _store.set_point(e->pos()) do and where do you add the points to the QGraphicsScene? Note that you do not need to call update() from the paint function.

Comment: The update() is called in the paint function as well. I have implemented in if condition as you may see above. Or should I be doing it somehow differently?